# Shruti (Gujarati) Fonts changes when download a Google Sheet as PDF

Tags: pdf, google-sheets, fonts, rendering

My File contains Gujarati Shruti fonts, which are typed using Google input tools, which is provided in Google Sheet menu. (When I changed the locale of file from United States to India(Gujarati), the menu of Gujarati Fonts was automatically added by Google Sheets.)

My Sample Google Sheet (with editable permissions) is
[Sample File.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JqvBI5cWk2jQ3KD0kUGDPV-7W7tbbUN5wkYNC8CaXdc/edit?usp=sharing)

And the downloaded PDF file (using the File > Download> PDF Documnet) is 
[Downloaded sample PDF file.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BvNfLLKmiTUmx1MTyq1qpb2DaKosmX5D/view?usp=sharing)

See the **highlighted (yellow) fonts** in PDF and Google Sheet, they are changed / corrupted in PDF. But surprisingly some fonts doesn't change.

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: @HBB20 now it is fixed by Google.

Answer (score 0):

Now Google has fixed this issue. When we download the file as PDF, it remains in same formatting, even if they are **made up of two or more half words** (**જોડ્યા શબ્દો**).